# How to list the newly added files or directories in the last n number of commits in GIT?

Tags: git

I need to add the files to my minification program, and I dont remember which files I added recently are not noted down in my minification program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAME

```
   git-whatchanged - Show logs with difference each commit introduces
```

SYNOPSIS

```
   git whatchanged <option>...
```

OPTIONS

```
   -<n>
       Limit output to <n> commits.
```

Seems like the 'n' option is what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only HEAD~n HEAD --
```

Where the n in `HEAD~n` is the number of commits back you want to look.  For instance

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only HEAD~5 HEAD --
```